# LWJGL/Java - Implementing a writeable text box?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

I would like to create a writeable text box where a user can input text into it. A nice "send" button that the person could click to send the text to the server would also be nice.

I currently haven no idea how to do this and I do not see any tutorials on how to do this.

I am using LWJGL and Java, and also I am using the Slick2D library.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be a standard windows input box or would you want to style it?

Comment: @Eejin Currently I have no text box. Soo.... Any text box would be far better than no text box to start me off :).

It would be nice if it was an in-application text box which can be stylized, but I cannot have everything and will take any solution that is better than nothing.

Comment: lwjgl includes tinyfiledialogs which offers an input box.

Answer (score 2):

LWJGL is just a binding of OpenGL, a way to buffer data to your graphics hardware.
Slick2D is a depreciated game library for rendering images, and telling LWJGL what to do.

Although, Slick2D does have a way to render True-Type font files as quadrilateral images. The TrueTypeFont class has more information on it.

Here's really good tutorial on NinjaCave: http://ninjacave.com/slickutil3

As for buttons, Slick2D does not natively support GUI. But there are really good libraries for GUI handling (With text integrated)
The most popular and configuable is nifty-ui: http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/